# How to get re-usable menu component?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to setup a simple React app having only AppBar I want a menu to open when ever I click on app-bar items, I am using material-ui for styling. When I click first time on either "Project" or "Edit" items, menu appears successfully but don't know how to handle closing of this menu. You can find the working sample on [codesandbox.io](https://codesandbox.io/s/objective-hertz-3tfkf?file=/src/menucontent.js:0-614).

**Please note that it is essential to maintain directory structure.**

appbaritems.js

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { Button, ButtonGroup } from "@material-ui/core";
import MenuContent from "./menucontent";

class AppBarItems extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = { menuAnchor: null };
  }

  handleClick = (event) => {
    this.setState({ menuAnchor: event.currentTarget });
  };
  handleClose = () => {
    this.setState({ menuAnchor: null });
  };
  render = () => {
    return (
      <div>
        <ButtonGroup
          variant="contained"
          color="primary"
          aria-label="contained primary button group"
        >
          <Button
            className="dense toolbarbutton"
            disableElevation
            onClick={this.handleClick}
          >
            Project
          </Button>
          <Button
            className="dense toolbarbutton"
            disableElevation
            onClick={this.handleClick}
          >
            Edit
          </Button>
          <Button className="dense toolbarbutton" disableElevation>
            View
          </Button>
          <Button className="dense toolbarbutton" disableElevation>
            Layer
          </Button>
          <Button className="dense toolbarbutton" disableElevation>
            Settings
          </Button>
          <Button className="dense toolbarbutton" disableElevation>
            Plugin
          </Button>
          <Button className="dense toolbarbutton" disableElevation>
            Vector
          </Button>
          <Button className="dense toolbarbutton" disableElevation>
            Raster
          </Button>
          <Button className="dense toolbarbutton" disableElevation>
            Database
          </Button>
          <Button className="dense toolbarbutton" disableElevation>
            Web
          </Button>
          <Button className="dense toolbarbutton" disableElevation>
            Processing
          </Button>
          <Button className="dense toolbarbutton" disableElevation>
            Help
          </Button>
        </ButtonGroup>
        <MenuContent anchorEl={this.state.menuAnchor} />
      </div>
    );
  };
}

export default AppBarItems;
```

meucontent.js

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { Menu, MenuItem } from "@material-ui/core";

class MenuContent extends Component {
  handleClose = () => {
    console.log("Don't know how to handle closing of this menu");
  };
  render = () => {
    return (
      <Menu
        elevation={0}
        anchorEl={this.props.anchorEl}
        open={Boolean(this.props.anchorEl)}
        onClose={this.handleClose}
      >
        <MenuItem>Item 1</MenuItem>
        <hr />
        <MenuItem>Item 2</MenuItem>
        <hr />
        <MenuItem>Item 3</MenuItem>
      </Menu>
    );
  };
}

export default MenuContent;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can leverage the `handleClose` method in your `AppBarItems` component. Simply pass this as prop to `MenuContent`

```
<MenuContent anchorEl={this.state.menuAnchor} handleClose={this.handleClose} />
```

On `MenuContent`, execute that prop `onClose`

```
<Menu
  elevation={0}
  anchorEl={this.props.anchorEl}
  open={Boolean(this.props.anchorEl)}
  onClose={this.props.handleClose}
>
```

If you need the `Menu` to close when a menu item is clicked as well, you can use the same prop `onClick` of a `MenuItem`

```
<MenuItem onClick={this.props.handleClose}>Item 1</MenuItem>
```

[image: Edit keen-murdock-6sx2t]

Comment: thanks that worked like a charm, I did not know that I was possible to pass method as prop.